# open source for call center compatible with CiviCRM

Tags: extension

I am a new CiviCRM user, I need a software open source compatible with CiviCRM to do a Call center (a bit like callhub).
Any suggestion will be welcome.

Thanks

Moustapha D.
SPA Canada
society for the protection of animals Canada

Answer (score 2):

According to Alternativeto.net, there are [no open source alternatives to Callhub](https://alternativeto.net/software/callhub/?license=opensource).  Arguably Asterisk VoIP is an alternative, but you would have to add a lot of software on top of it.

Regardless - while [Callhub has CiviCRM integration](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-extension-for-callhub-phonebanks), there are no alternatives that already have CiviCRM integration.  You would have to create it yourself.

Comment: Jon - was that second link meant to go somewhere else? eg https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-extension-for-callhub-phonebanks

Comment: Yes @petednz-fuzion - fixed now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you don't get something 3rd-party that suits I could describe to you how we have approached something like this using Drupal Views and Webforms. However we have not taken it to the point of then using dialling from the screen.

But what it does allow is for an Admin to allocate calls to the callers, or callers can self-allocate.

The caller then clicks on their next call and it loads up data about the person to be called above the webform that will record the outcome of the call.

Depending on the outcome, calls are either set to remain on the callers list (eg for a No Answer) or given an outcome that may require follow up etc, or just Closed.

All of this data is recorded in CiviCRM as Activities so it is easy to track both the efforts of the callers and the outcomes of the calls.